# Jenkins: clone a private repository in a docker container

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, ssh, git-clone

I know there are numerous questions about this topic already here on SO, and I tried almost all of the solutions they came up with, but I'm currently at the point that I can't get it to work (the way I want that is).

### Problem

I have docker container that is spinned up in Jenkins, and in this docker container I try to clone a private repository. To do this I need to add my public Jenkins key to my Git repository and my docker container needs to know this SSH key.

### My current working solution

I am already able to do this by doing the following in my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
docker.image('php_jenkins_test').inside('--env COMPOSER_HOME=$WORKSPACE/.composer -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /home/jenkins/.ssh:/home/jenkins/.ssh:ro') {
    sshagent(['jenkins-ssh-publickey']) {
        sh "./test/run-tests.sh"
    }
}
```

I mount my `etc/passwd` and `/home/jenkins/.ssh` as read-only volumes for the following reasons:

- The Jenkins Docker plugin runs as a Jenkins user. This users' UID and GID are not known inside my Docker container. Therefore I had to mount `/etc/passwd`.
- When pulling from the Git repo, my `known_hosts` (and my keys?) need to be known inside my docker container. Since `/etc/passwd` maps the jenkins users to `/home/jenkins`, I had to mount the SSH-directory of Jenkins on my guest machine as well.
- The `sshagent`-command sets up the SSH socket so that my keys are accessible within my container (correct me if I'm wrong, I'm fairly new to Jenkins and Docker).

Like I said: this already works. With this setup I am able to clone private git repositories within my docker container within Jenkins.

### So what's the problem then?

I find mounting of `/home/jenkins/.ssh` a bit... dangerous. I mount it as read-only, but I work in an organization with 70+ developers and if one of them takes my code as example and removes the `:ro`, chances are they are going to mess up Jenkins' `.ssh`-folder and this is very, very bad.

So I'm looking for a method to clone private repositories without having to mount the `.ssh`-folder. After all, isn't that what the `sshagent`-plugin is for?

### What I have tried so far

Since my docker container mounts the `/etc/passwd` it will look for a `/home/jenkins`-folder at some point in time. Since the `sshagent` will take care of the keys I figured I would only have to be concerned about the `known_hosts`-file. So I tried the following in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/jenkins/.ssh
RUN chmod 700 /home/jenkins/.ssh
RUN ssh-keyscan -t rsa (url to git) >> /home/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Unfortunately, this will create the directories and files under the `root`-user, so when I run my container as the `jenkins`-user (what the Jenkins docker plugin does), I cannot access `/home/jenkins/...`.

So I tried doing it in a shell script in my container that is ran by the Jenkins user:

```
mkdir -p /home/jenkins/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/jenkins/.ssh
ssh-keyscan -t rsa (url to git) >> /home/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Once again: no luck, since the jenkins-user is not allowed to create directories in `/home/`.

So back to `Dockerfile`, let's try adding the following line:

```
RUN chown $(id -u $(whoami)):$(id -g $(whoami)) -R /home/jenkins
```

Again no luck, because `whoami` returns `root`, not `jenkins`. So let's just hard-code it in then:

```
RUN chown $(id -u jenkins):$(id -g jenkins) -R /home/jenkins
```

Once again, no luck. The message I get now is *"id: jenkins: no such user"*.

### I'm stuck

So there you have it: I'm stuck. **How can I clone private repositories in a docker container in Jenkins without having to mount the `.ssh`-folder?** Any help on this topic is greatly appreciated. I'm staring at this for too long now...

Comment: In `RUN chown $(id -u jenkins):$(id -g jenkins) -R /home/jenkins` use the uid of the jenkins user rather than `jenkins`

Comment: Our Jenkins CI server has 3 slaves. Because of this the uid is not the same on all machines. So I cannot hardcode the uid.

Comment: I've been stuck with this for a while and even in the fancy new world of Jenkins pipelines with Docker I'm not sure there is a better way than mounting those directories.

Comment: were you able to find other solutions? im having similar problem here